# Overwrite login page

Tags: theming, users

I'm trying to overwrite the **FULL LOGIN PAGE**, not only the login form!

I've tried this

```
function your_themename_theme() {
  $items = array();
  // create custom user-login.tpl.php
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'your_themename') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'user-login',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
  'your_themename_preprocess_user_login'
  ),
 );
return $items;
}
```

and this:

```
function YOURTHEME_theme() {
  return array(
    'user_login' => array(
      'template' => 'user-login',
      'variables' => array('form' => NULL), ## you may remove this line in this case
    )
  );
}
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_user_login(&$variables) {
    $variables['form'] = drupal_build_form('user_login', user_login(array(),$form_state)); ## I have to build the user login myself.
}
```

but that's only working for my login form. I have a website with all same layout pages but only the login is different. How can I disable regions and edit css from my login page?

**UPDATE**:

Now I changed the name of the template to `page--user--login.tpl` and when I put `<p>test</p>` in my the template I see `test` in my browser. But when I type nothing I see the login form but also my sidebar/footer. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal method for creating a custom `page--user--login.tpl.php` is *not* to create an empty file, but to *copy* the  `page.tpl.php` supplied with the theme you're using into the `templates/`-directory of your sub-theme, rename it `page--user--login.tpl.php`, and edit the copy.

For instance, to remove the footer, just locate the markup in your copied `page--user--login.tpl.php` that is used to template the footer, and delete it!

```
<div id="footer-wrapper"><div class="section">

  <?php if ($page['footer_firstcolumn'] || $page['footer_secondcolumn'] || $page['footer_thirdcolumn'] || $page['footer_fourthcolumn']): ?>
    <div id="footer-columns" class="clearfix">
      <?php print render($page['footer_firstcolumn']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['footer_secondcolumn']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['footer_thirdcolumn']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['footer_fourthcolumn']); ?>
    </div> <!-- /#footer-columns -->
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($page['footer']): ?>
    <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
      <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
    </div> <!-- /#footer -->
  <?php endif; ?>

</div></div> <!-- /.section, /#footer-wrapper -->
```

The block above is an example of how this may look like (this is from a copy of *Bartik*), if you copy it from another theme, it may look different.

But to get rid of it, you pull it into your favourite text editor and delete all of it.

Comment: but my page--user--login.tpl.php is empty

Comment: Ok, but how can I do this the right way?

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I just have to copy the page.tpl.php, rename to page--user--login.tpl.php and remove the parts I don't want, is this the right way?

Comment: Yup - that's it!